# 1&1 server with paypal express checkout is not working

Tags: express-checkout

I am using a php (curl) based PayPal express checkout script and it works just fine on my localhost and with GoDaddy server, however, with 1&1 server I just get a blank page.

I need to know how to set up a proxy in order to access the PayPal server.

I am new at this and would appreciate any help.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer myself. I placed these codes at the beginning of my pages that were concerned with the paypal checkout process.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

As a result I found an error with the headers that were already posted.

I placed an

```
 <?php ob_start();?>
```

at the beginning of all those pages and everything works just fine.